# Simple port forwarding with iptables

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

I start with the following which doesn't seem necessary, but it doesn't seem to hurt:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

The following two commands create port forwarding from port 5433 to port 5432.

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5433 -m comment --comment "Port forward 5433->5432" -j REDIRECT --to-ports 5432
sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5433 -m comment --comment "Port forward 5433->5432" -j REDIRECT --to-ports 5432
```

This works locally. Both of the following commands successfully connect and get "Empty reply" because the listening server is not HTTP.

```
curl http://localhost:5432
curl http://localhost:5433
```

However, when I run the same commands from another server:

```
curl http://<local IP>:5432
curl http://<local IP>:5433
```

The 5432 curl connects, but the 5433 curl does not, which means the port forwarding doesn't seem to work from a remote server.

How can I fix my iptables rules to make port forwarding work from remote servers as well as local servers?

I see the second rule specifies a "source" IP of 127.0.0.1/32. I tried changing this and couldn't find something that worked.

Comment: In general the problem with `-A` is that it Appends a new rule to the existing rule set and that may or may not have any effect at all. That can't be judged from the individual command .. please take a look at the complete firewall configuration

Comment: Have you done testing from remote computer? the PREROUTING rule only applies to traffic that comes in on eth0, but it also applies to all traffic regardless of destination IP.

use `iptables -vnL -t nat` to list all rules, see if anything conflicts (happens before) but also check the counters to know if the rule was invoked or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is two things that you should know.

You should add rule for MASQUERADE in your NAT block [see instruction there, for example](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Security_Guide/s1-firewall-ipt-fwd.html), for whole interface or only for one port. And you should allow forwarding by removing rule in filter block, if it exist in your iptables config.